# What are some concrete examples of kinds of relations in math?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I'm writing an undergrad philosophy paper. My take on the issue is that the conceptual problem I'm addressing is only a problem because the word 'is' and 'relation' are too slippery. By more precisely defining the relationship in question, I suspect that the problem can be solved.

I'm just learning predicate logic now, and otherwise math is something I'm looking forward to knowing more about, but don't know much about now (so please go easy on the notation).

Do I understand these relationships correctly (by example):

**antitransitivity:** links in a chain - link a is connected (related) to b, b to c, but not a to c.

**intransitivity:** strands in a rope - where each fiber might run all the way from end to end, but not necessarily. So if a fiber is adjacent to a fiber at some point in its length they have a relationship for the purpose of this example. It may be that fiber a connects with fibers b and c, but not necessarily, although it must connect with fiber b.

**transitivity:** 'is an ancestor of': Adam begat Seth, Seth begat Enoch, Enoch begat Methuselah. so, Adam is an ancestor of x would apply to Seth, Enoch, and Methuselah and that would be a transitive relationship.

**reflexivity** 'is' of identity. Bruce Wayne 'is' Batman, and Batman 'is' Bruce Wayne. or "x shares my hair color"

**irreflexivity** 'is not' of identity. a 'is not' b. or "x does not share my hair colour"

**symmetry** links in a chain might work here too. A link a is connected to b in the same way b is connected to a? or 'in contact with' e.g. a hand is in contact with a rail, and a rail is in contact with a hand.

**asymmetry** "entails" rain entails wetness, but wetness does not entail rain.

**trichotomous** this one's a stretch. Two twins are born. Either a came out before b, or b before a, or they came out at the same time.

Hopefully I understood the concepts above, but the following three I don't really get.

**anti-symmetry**

**quasi-reflexivity**

**co-reflexivity**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See Rosen: Chapter 8: Relations.

Comment: By the way, is implies that it is an "if" statement. So it's equality in one direction.

Comment: What you wrote seems mostly okay (although rather vague) but I can't tell whether or not you understand reflexivity and irreflexivity.  It's true that $=$ is reflexive and $\ne$ is irreflexive.  To see this, we just have to note that for all $x$ we have $x=x$ and we do not have $x \ne x$.

Comment: By the way, I have never heard of quasi-reflexivity or co-reflexivity, so I think it might not be very important to understand them.

Comment: For an example of an anti-symmetric relation, consider the relation "is not in front of" on a single-file line of people.  If person $A$ is not in front of person $B$, and person $B$ is not in front of person $A$, then $A$ and $B$ must be the same person.

Comment: @TrevorWilson I actually couldn't think of any other non-abstract (ir)reflexive relations. But in words, I think that 'reflexive' is when two things are related to each other in the same way. - I'm not clear on how its different from a symmetrical relation.

Comment: Relation is mostly a primitive term. Maybe the most you can say is that a relation allows you to compare, and order some of the elements (partial order), or all the elements ( total order). As to 'is', maybe you can ask Bill Clinton just what 'is' is.

Comment: Many useful relations are both symmetric and reflexive (_e.g._ relations of the form "$A$ has the same ___ as $B$") so it can be difficult to separate them.  But the relation "is at least as old as" is reflexive (everyone is at least as old as himself/herself) and not symmetric, and the relation "lives exactly one mile away from" is symmetric but not reflexive.)

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean by "shares a property" then the relations you get this way are exactly the equivalence relations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation.  (But perhaps you mean something else; I never can tell with philosophers :-)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what keeps us in business.

Comment: And I've got to recall the 'shares a property' thing. That's what seems to be meant by 'related', but I don't think it has to be - so that's what brought me to reading about relationships. Thank you for the answers, it's clarified much.

Comment: Yes, probably the mathematical definition of "relation" includes some strange things that the philosophers wouldn't consider as relations.  Anyway, I'm glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn’t seen the terms [*coreflexive relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreflexive_relation) and [*quasi-reflexive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-reflexive_relation#Related_terms) relation before, but the definitions are fairly straightforward, especially that of coreflexivity.

- A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is *coreflexive* if it is a subset of the identity relation on $A$; this is equivalent to saying that for all $x,y\in A$, if $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$, then $x=y$. In particular, the identity relation itself and the empty relation are both coreflexive. A silly but less trivial example on the set of people: *is male and is the same person as*. Being male, I stand in this relation to myself, but me sister Patty does not stand in this relation to anyone. Clearly one can stand in this relation **only** to oneself, but roughly half the population, being female, does not stand in this relation to anyone.
- A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is *quasi-reflexive* if every element of $A$ that is related to at least one element of $A$ is related to itself. However, there might be elements of $A$ that are not related to any element of $A$, including themselves. An example on the set of people is *has at least one living parent in common with*: if you have a living parent in common with anyone, you have one in common with yourself. I have no living parent, however, so I do not stand in this relation to myself.